# Multiple showmore and show less in a page

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having a 12 static images and it should display 3 images first and then show more. After clicking show more it should display the next three images with show more and after clicking that it should display progressively. After displaying 12 images it should display show less and clicking on showless should show the first 3 images with show more. All these has to be done in mobile browsers.

Can someone give me an idea on how to proceed.

HTML

```
<div id ="expandOptions"class="row" [ngClass]="showMore ? 'show-options-more' : 'show-options'">
  <div class="col-md-12 list-images">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 01.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 02.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 03.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 list-images">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 04.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 05.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 06.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 list-images">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 07.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 08.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 09.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 list-images">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 10.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 11.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="img-wrap" src=" 12.jpg" alt=" check">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 show-more" (click)="clickShowMore()">
  <button class="btn btn-link" [hidden]="showMore"> show more </button>
  <button class="btn btn-link" [hidden]="!showMore"> show less </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, do not use bold text: it's like shouting.

Comment: I remove the bold text before I will becomes blind :)

Answer (score 0):

a simple [pipe slice](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) make the trick

```html
    <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]|slice:0:num">
       <img [src]="('00'+i).slice(-2)+'.jpg'">
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="num<12" (click)="num=num+3">more</button>
    <button *ngIf="num>3" (click)="num=num=-3">less</button>
```

And declare a variable

```
num:number=3
```